# Video player resets after window resize in responsive react web app?

Tags: reactjs, responsive-design, antd

I am having trouble getting a video player to persist playing after a window resize in my responsive web app. I am using the react-responsive library to help with this. I have a different MediaQuery element handling each window size range in my outer "content" component which handles the overall page layout using antd layout component, so I'm guessing what is happening is a different part of the component is showing for each range, causing the video to also "reset" each time a new range is detected. (The problem goes away when I remove the media queries.)

How do I make it so that when the video player is currently playing the video(which is an iframe rendering an api resource), it continues to play through a window resize into a different range? I'm guessing I can change the media query ranges and nest them in some specific way but I can't figure out how to do this.

the page layout in the content component:

```
const Inside = props => (
  <Layout.Content
    style={{
      background: '#fff',
      padding: '10px 10px',
      width: props.width,
      margin: '0 auto 50px',
    }}
  >
    <main>
      <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
      <Route path="/quicklooks" component={Quicklooks} />
      <Route path="/features" component={Features} />
      <Route path="/bombcasts" component={Bombcasts} />
    </main>
  </Layout.Content>
);

const Content = () => (
  <div>
    <XS><Inside width="100%" /></XS>
    <SM><Inside width="100%" /></SM>
    <MD><Inside width="740px" /></MD>
    <LG><Inside width="940px" /></LG>
    <XL><Inside width="1160px" /></XL>
    <XXL><Inside width="1160px" /></XXL>
  </div>
);
```

the video player:

```
const CurrentVideo = (props) => {
  const pubDateFormatted = Moment(props.pub_date).format('MMM. D, YYYY h:mma');

  return (
    <div style={{ background: '#000', margin: '0 auto', width: '100%' }}>
      <Row type="flex" justify="center">
        <Col xs={24} lg={8}>
          <div style={{ padding: '16px', color: '#fff' }}>
            <h2 style={{ color: '#fff' }}>{props.name}</h2>
            <p><i> Posted by {props.user} | {pubDateFormatted}</i></p>
            <p>{props.deck}</p>
          </div>
        </Col>
        <Col xs={24} lg={16} >
          <div className="intrinsic-container intrinsic-container-16x9">
            <iframe
              frameBorder={0}
              allowFullScreen
              title={props.name}
              src={props.embed_player}
            />
          </div>
        </Col>
      </Row>
    </div>
  );
};

CurrentVideo.propTypes = {
  name: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  user: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  pub_date: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  deck: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  embed_player: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
};

export default CurrentVideo;
```

the different media queries set to specific window widths:

```
export const XXL = props => (
  <Responsive minWidth={1600}>
    {props.children}
  </Responsive>
);

export const XL = props => (
  <Responsive minWidth={1200} maxWidth={1599}>
    {props.children}
  </Responsive>
);

export const LG = props => (
  <Responsive minWidth={992} maxWidth={1199}>
    {props.children}
  </Responsive>
);
export const MD = props => (
  <Responsive minWidth={768} maxWidth={991}>
    {props.children}
  </Responsive>
);

export const SM = props => (
  <Responsive minWidth={576} maxWidth={767}>
    {props.children}
  </Responsive>
);

export const XS = props => (
  <Responsive maxWidth={575}>
    {props.children}
  </Responsive>
);
```

Answer (score 2):

You should take a look at the [React rules for reconciliation](https://reactjs.org/docs/reconciliation.html). They say: "Whenever the root elements have different types, React will tear down the old tree and build the new tree from scratch."

It looks like what's happening here is that when the screen size changes, a new component with a different type is getting created, ultimately causing `CurrentVideo` to be torn down and replaced.

Don't use react-responsive here. Use React to set up the dom elements, then use [normal CSS media queries](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_mediaqueries.asp) to change the display based on window size.

If you really insist on using react-responsive, you could try rendering the `iframe` in `Inside`, passing it a `ref` argument to allow you to store a reference to the dom element (take a look at [Refs and the DOM](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html)), and then passing that reference down to the `CurrentVideo`.

Comment: Thank you! Using css media queries solved the problem. I suppose currentVideo component being replaced rather than re-rendered would also explain why using shouldComponentUpdate didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Without digging too much into your implementation, my guess would be that react-responsive is causing the CurrentVideo component to re-render.

One possible way to mitigate that would be to use the `shouldComponentUpdate()` method to block re-rendering, then check if the component's props or state have actually changed enough for a re-render to be required. There's more information on the lifecycle methods and `shouldComponentUpdate()` specifically in the [React Docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#shouldcomponentupdate)

Comment: Oh yeah, I forgot to mention that I did try using `shouldComponentUpdate`, setting it to return false if the props inside currentVideo didn't change. But using css queries per @J. Kamien's suggesting seemed to work. Thank you though.